# JSON key value coming as blank when using JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am using JQ to parse JSON returned by Salesforce CLI.
My bash script is:

```
orgCreateResult=$(sfdx force:org:display -u mockScreenOrg --json)
orgCreateStatus=$(echo $orgCreateResult | ./bash-scripts/jq-win64.exe .status -r)
echo "orgCreateResult: "
echo "$orgCreateResult"
echo "orgCreateStatus: $orgCreateStatus"
instanceUrl=$(echo $checkDevHubResult | ./bash-scripts/jq-win64.exe .result -r)
echo "instanceUrl: $instanceUrl"
```

I am using bash terminal in VS Code on windows. Output I am getting from this script is :

```
orgCreateResult:
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "username": "test-******@example.com",
    "devHubId": "****@**.com",
    "id": "************",
    "createdBy": "*****@**.com",
    "createdDate": "2019-05-13T14:15:32.000+0000",
    "expirationDate": "2019-06-12",
    "status": "Active",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "orgName": "HPESC",
    "accessToken": "************************************",
    "instanceUrl": "https://nosoftware-ruby-2532-dev-ed.cs6.my.salesforce.com",
    "clientId": "PlatformCLI",
    "alias": "mockScreenOrg"
  }
}
orgCreateStatus: 0
instanceUrl:
```

I am able to read status field from JSON but it kinda fails with result object. I want to read instanceUrl field from JSON to use later in my script. Not sure if I am doing something wrong. I am very new to bash and JQ

Comment: Where does `$checkDevHubResult` come from?

Comment: If logged with `bash -x yourscript`, you'd see the actual invocations, so you could build a reproducer that's self-contained and doesn't depend on variable values that aren't shown.

Comment: That's it. Just a variable name issue.

Comment: BTW, note that `echo $foo` is itself generally buggy; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)

Comment: Yes, I read it that echo is not recommended but I am very new to all this and not aware of any other way to do pipe my result json to JQ. Otherwise i have to do it in single line which is kinda messy and repetitive as i have to execute same command multiple times to get values from a single json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`instanceUrl=$(echo $orgCreateResult | ./bash-scripts/jq-win64.exe .result.instanceUrl -r)`